# Route from Cisco ASA over site to site VPN

Tags: cisco-asa, syslog, route, site-to-site-vpn

I want to be able to push f/w logging traffic to a server at a remote site.  This server is accepting syslog traffic on port 514.  In the ASA I've configured it to use this server as a syslog server.

The Cisco f/w's inside interface address is 10.0.0.1 and I want to route over the link to an address of 192.168.1.1.  The vpn is up and working between sites, and local clients at each site can access resources etc.

How would I go about setting up the route from the f/w to this remote server only?

Comment: Is the ASA's inside interface in one of the subnets that's being sent over the VPN?

Comment: Yes.  The local network on the ASA side is 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0.  ASA IP is 10.0.0.1.

Comment: is the host 192.168.1.1 or the subnet the host exists on a part of the vpn encryption domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the remote site, set the logging host inside `<ipnr syslogserver>`
and make sure to set the management interface on inside.

So this should cover it:

- management-access inside
- logging host inside **ipnr syslogserver**